# Is it legal to return reference to an InputIterator internal state?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, language-lawyer

Let we have an input iterator `it` that conforms [Cpp17InputIterator](http://eel.is/c++draft/input.iterators#tab:inputiterator). Can we guarantee that the reference value `*it` remains the same after we do `it++`? For example,

```cpp
const auto &old_ref = *it;
auto old_val = ref;
++it; // old_ref might be affected by this

assert(old_ref == old_val); // Is this guaranteed for Cpp17InputIterator?
```

This [table](http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:inputiterator) says that the old copies of `it` are not required to be dereferenceable. But does this imply that old references obtained from `it` may not be dereferenceable too? Can `*it` return a reference to the iterator's internal state?

Comment: Quoting the link you posted, "any copies of the previous value of r are no longer required to be dereferenceable" would imply that any reference is invalidated -- so no, this is not safe to expect to work with input iterators

Comment: basically it prepends on iterator. For example `std::istream_iterator` would do something funny here (assertion will fail). https://godbolt.org/z/Pzn5aW

Comment: I am not sure about this implication: "`*old_it` is invalid implies that `old_ref` is invalid".

Comment: Not necessary. If this is iterator to container which is not modified, reference remains valid.

Comment: I can't find anything about this specifically in the "concepts" bit. For istream_iterator specifically there's [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/istream.iterator.general) section which actually suggests there's only one "dereferenced value object" and thus your reference should remain valid. But I'm grasping at straws a bit as this seems only very weakly specified. This also depends on how we should interpret "exposition only" as it relates to specified _uses_ of exposition-only members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should never be assumed that a reference remains valid if an iterator is invalidated. This *may* be the case with *some* iterator implementations, but doing so is a violation of the iterator concept, and will not work generically with all iterators.

It's entirely legal for an iterator to be implemented internally as a `std::optional<T>` that may return a reference  of `T` and reconstructs `T` between each iteration. This is especially true on `Inputiterator`s, which don't require multipass support (such as for a generator range).

For example, an iterator doing the following is completely legal:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto some_special_iterator<T>::operator*() -> T&
{
  return *m_value; // returns a reference to the currently stored T
}

template <typename T>
auto some_special_iterator<T>::operator++() -> some_special_iterator&
{
  m_value.clear(); // Destroys the object which someone may be holding a reference to
  m_value.emplace( ... ); // Invalidates any existing references by constructing a new object

  return (*this);
}
```

Using a pointer or reference to an object that has been destroyed is **undefined behavior**, even if that pointer or reference points to the same storage of a new object. The only legal pointers or references to a newly constructed object are the ones returned by `new` (such as placement `new`) or `std::launder`.

---

Since this is tagged [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer): There isn't really much in the line of quotes directly from the standard that can define this to be illegal, since there are no guarantees from the `InputIterator` concept that allow a preserved reference to remain valid.

So to prove this is undefined behavior, we need to work backwards. First off:

From [defns.undefined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.undefined)

> Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit definition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data

So we need to check that the iterator example above adheres correctly to `InputIterator`'s concept definition, of which the important part is the `operator++` behavior:

From the table in [input.iterators](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/input.iterators):

> Requires: r is dereferenceable. 
> Postconditions: r is dereferenceable or r is past-the-end;
> **any copies of the previous value of r are no longer required either to be dereferenceable or to be in the domain of ==.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

In the above requirements, the condition that an iterator `r` is dereferencable before is upheld in the above example, just as the postcondition would be upheld as well.

What's interesting is the part that I bolded: "any copies of the *previous value of r* are no longer required either to be dereferenceable or to be in the domain of =="

This means that any existing copies of the iterator itself may no longer be dereferenceable and nor may it properly perform a comparison in the same range as another iterator. This is the part that formally means that **all copies of the iterator *may* have been invalidated** (note: "may", since an iterator need not be invalidated -- but should be assumed to have).

The C++ Standard's document does not *explicitly* state that any held references are still valid, because this is not defined behavior of the process; however if the iterator itself is no longer considered "dereferencable" after an invocation of `operator++`, then it should also be assumed that its reference is no longer valid. Since the wording does not state that holding a reference after this point is guaranteed to remain valid, it must be assumed to be undefined behavior due to the passage above from `defns.undefined`.

The example illustrated above is a conforming iterator implementation where such an expectation would cause actual undefined behavior, which fits this interpretation.

---

On a different note, be careful using `const auto&` with input iterators.

`operator*()` on input iterators only needs to return an `It::reference` type which *is convertible to* `T`; it does not actually need to be a reference at all. Be aware that this is strengthened in forward iterators and beyond that "`reference` must be a reference to `T`", but this isn't true of input iterators.

Using `const auto&` here may actually cause you to unintentionally `const`-lifetime-extend a temporary proxy object rather than holding a real reference.

Comment: I thought that "iterator invalidation" thing is related solely to container operations. Is it correct to say that `++it` "invalidates" the iterator? Why?

Comment: You can have iterators that do not refer to containers. `istream_iterator`, for example.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some quotes for the `language-lawyer` tag. There isn't anything explicitly stating a held reference may be invalidated, but nor is there anything stating that it should remain valid either. Since an iterator like my example is a valid `InputIterator`, holding a reference to its internal state would formally be undefined behavior -- thanks to `defns.undefined` since the document never identifies this to be safe to perform